# oracle listagg - result of string concatenation is too long

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I have a problem that I can't solve. I have this statement:

```
SELECT account,
    listagg(field1 || ', ') WITHIN
GROUP (
        ORDER BY field1
        ) AS field1
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY account
```

I am getting an error:

> ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
>   01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long"
>   *Cause:    String concatenation result is more than the maximum size.
>   *Action:   Make sure that the result is less than the maximum size.

How to solve? I tried to do this, but it did not help

```
SUBSTR(listagg(field1 || ', ') WITHIN
GROUP (
        ORDER BY field1
        ), 1, 500) AS field1
```

Comment: If the concatenation be too long, then wouldn't the obvious solution be to truncate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Results of SQL functions returning strings must fit within the maximum limit, which was 4000 (now 32K in Oracle 12c if `max_string_size=extended`).

You can't truncate it with `SUBSTR` because by then it's too late - it's the `LISTAGG` function itself which is raising the exception.

The only way around this is to ensure that the number of records being concatenated is limited - for example, by putting a maximum cap on the number of records returned for each `account`, and/or by truncating the length of each `field1` itself.

Comment: @Lalit, thanks that's right, would just need some changes to the application.